# Iterative Newton's Method to recursive (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration, newtons-method

I need to use Newton's method using recursion. I have this piece of code using iterative Newton's method, but I'm very new to programming so I can't wrap my head around how to turn it into recursion. I would really appreciate some visual demonstration.

```
public static double f(double x){ 
    return x*x*x-3.5*x*x+0.5*x + 5;
}
public static double prf(double x) { 
    return 3 * x * x - 7 * x + 0.5;
}
// ВЫЧИСЛЕНИЕ КОРНЯ МЕТОДОМ НЬЮТОНА
public static double x_newton(double a, double e) {
    double x = a; 
    double razn;
    do {
        double xn = x - f(x) / prf(x); 
        razn = Math.abs(xn - x); 
        x = xn; 
    } while (razn > e); 

    return x - f(x)/prf(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we want to go other way around, that is, eliminate the recursion. In case of a tail recursion:

```
func(arguments) {
    if (condition) {
        return something(arguments)
    }
    arguments = modify_arguments(arguments)
    return func(arguments)
}
```

there is a mechanical rewrite:

```
func(arguments) {
    while (!condition) {
        arguments = modify_arguments(arguments)
    }
    return something(arguments)
}
```

Now you only need to apply it backwards.

---

That said, `while (razn > e)` is not a robust way to terminate the loop. In case the derivative is very large, it may terminate too early, far away from the root.

Also, use English for identifiers. `razn` looks equally ugly for both Russian and English reader. `delta_x` is way better. Ditto for `pr`.